# jQuery Magnify: Add same image for "data-magnify-src"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jQuery for embedding items in a lightbox. Now I would like to add [Magnify](https://thdoan.github.io/magnify/).

The image tag should look like this in the end:

```
<img src="myimage.jpg" data-magnify-src="myimage.jpg"/>
```

The `src="myimage.jpg"` works. I want to add the same image (in the same size) for `data-magnify-src`.

This is my try:

```js
function openLightbox(element) {
  lightboxItem($(element).next().html());
  if (element && element.src) {
    const img = $("#lightbox img")[0];
    img.src = element.src;
    // img.data-magnify-src = element.src; ~ Does not work.
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="lightbox">
  <img class="zoom"/>
</div>
```

The image for `data-magnify-src` should be the same like for `src`.

Would be very happy if somebody could help me! :)

Answer (score 0):

use this
your html

```
<div id="lightbox">
  <img src="yourImage.jpg" class="zoom"/>
</div>
```

```
function openLightbox(element) {
  lightboxItem($(element).next().html());
  if (element && element.src) {
    const img = $("#lightbox img");
    const src = img.attr('src');
    img.data('magnify-src', src);
    $('.zoom').magnify(); // you need to re init after adding the data attr
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please create a codepen or sand box. I am sure we are missing something